# oracle plsql procedure dynamic count of the tables in cursor loop

Tags: plsql

I want to update all the tables having ABC column.Need to skip the tables which doesn't have data.I am having problem in checking the count of the table in a cursor loop.
PLSQL code

```
create or replace procedure testp is

  CURSOR c_testp
IS

    SELECT table_name,
      column_name
    FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE column_name IN('ABC') 
    ORDER BY table_name;

c int;

BEGIN

  FOR table_rec IN c_testp

  LOOP

    BEGIN

      SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO c
      FROM table_rec.table_name;
      IF(c>0) THEN
        query := 'update '||table_rec.table_name||' set '||table_rec.column_name ||'= xyz';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
       COMMIT;
      END IF;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('data not found');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('others');
    END;
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: You don't need to check the row count. If there are no rows in the table the `update` won't do anything. Just remove that part (but to answer the question: you need dynamic SQL for that as well).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, use this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || table_rec.table_name INTO c;
```

instead of this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO c
      FROM table_rec.table_name;
```

However, as mentioned in comments - there is actually no need to perform that condition check, as no `update` will be performed when `table` is empty.